# How to pass an error message without a bag in Laravel/Inertia?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to validate some data this way:

```php
public function update($user, array $input)
    {
        $v = Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)],
            'photo' => ['nullable', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png', 'max:1024'],
        ]);
      //MORE CODE 
}
```

Then, in place of "//MORE CODE", I tried to do this:

```php
$messagesArray = [];
        foreach ($v->messages()->all() as $message) {
            $messagesArray[] = $message;
        }
        if($v->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($messagesArray, 'errors');
        }
```

I tried other possibilities too (without success) like using the `Request $request` as a parameter but for some reason that I don't know, I'm not allowed to.

## The Problem

My problem is that I'm working with a huge application where I can't work with the **bag** at the client-side. I need to deliver the error props as an single Object (like: `{'errors' : {0:"error1", 1:"error2"...}}`), but I'm delivering something like this at the moment: `{'errors': {pagename:{0:"error1, 1:"error2"}}}`, that is I can't pass the errors in **bags**.

#### Last Comment

I know that the Validator class has the `validateWithBag()` method and I wondered if there wasn't some option like `validateWithoutBag()`...

*I already read the Laravel documentation and other questions, but... nothing*

Thank you for reading it!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Just return a list of validation errors? Why can't your client-side code just work with the format Laravel returns?

Comment: I solved it. Maybe it became more clear in my answer. I couldn't work with the bags because all of the application was using the same Vue Component for rendering error messages at the top of the pages. This component was using the "v-for" directive. If the error message would come from an object of an object, it will give an error.

Comment: Why you don't just use `redirect()->back()->with('name', 'yourResponse')`? you don't have to use `withErrors()` do send information back. it's here in the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data).

Comment: It actually worked too. Thanks, I will think about it in the next time

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. the errorBags are set at the Vue Components.
For example:

```js
this.form.post(route("user-profile-information.update"), {
   errorBag: "updateProfileInformation",
   preserveScroll: true,
   onSuccess: () => this.clearPhotoFileInput(),
});
```

At this snippet, the client set the errorBag, not the server-side.

#### Validate Without Bag

To validate without the bag, you must change `->validateWithBag("BagName");` for `->validate();` and remove the `errorBag: "BagName"` at your Vue Component.